# C compiler not finding gmp linked library

Tags: c, gmp

I'm trying to compile a simple C program on an M1 Mac that includes `gmp.h`. For whatever reason, however, it continuously says that it can't find the library. I checked to see if it exists via `locate libgmp.a` to which it says it is located in `/opt/local/lib/libgmp.a`. I also attempted to install it via `brew` to no avail. I really don't understand what I'm doing wrong here. I also checked the PATH environment variable to make sure this path was included, which it is.

The output of `find /opt/local -type f -name "gmp.h"` is `/opt/local/include/gmp.h`, and the output of `find /opt/local -type f -name "libgmp*"` is

```
/opt/local/libgmp.a
/opt/local/lib/libgmpxx.4.dylib
/opt/local/lib/libgmp.a
/opt/local/lib/libgmpxx.a
/opt/local/lib/libgmp.10.dylib
```

I compiled by linking via `-L/opt/local/lib -lgmp` does not fix the issue.

Command used: `gcc main.c -o main.o -L/opt/local/lib -lgmp`

Comment: How do you build your program?  You either need to list the .a file when you link your program, or tell the compiler the search directory and library you want to link with -L/opt/local/lib -lgmp (this is gcc syntax, you didn't say what compiler you are using).

Comment: What does `find /opt/local -type f -name "gmp.h"` report? (add result to question) along with result of `find /opt/local -type f -name "libgmp*"`

Comment: @AllanWind I added the command I used to the post. Linking with these flags (which I already tried) does not work.

Comment: Did you also add `-I/opt/local/include` to allow the compiler to find the header? (and ... you have `#include <gmp.h>` in your code?) The rest of your compile string looks correct.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yes, I do include the header. Adding that flag/arg made it work. I'm not entirely sure why, though. I thought all that was necessary was linking via -lgmp?

Comment: Any time you have things in non-standard locations `-I/path/to/header` adds `/path/to/header` to your *Include Search Path* (allowing the header to be found), and `-L/path/to/lib` adds `/path/to/lib` to your *Library Search Path* (allowing the library to be found). You can have multiple entries for each (one for every place you need to tell the compiler to look)

Comment: If you compile main.c you usually do it with -c, and if you build it then the output is not usually a .o file (i.e. gcc main.c -o program -L/opt/local/lib -lgmp).  What's the exact error message?  You get that when you build or when you try to run the program?

Comment: As @AllanWind indicates, I'd just use `gcc main.c -o main -I/opt/local/incude -L/opt/local/lib -lgmp` and compile to `main` as the executable. (actually I'd do `gcc main.c -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow -std=c11 -Ofast -o main -I/opt/local/incude -L/opt/local/lib -lgmp`  to enable *Full Warnings*. (never accept code until it compiles without warning)

Comment: Oh... so the error was that it could not find the header file.  Yeah, -I/opt/local/include will fix that.  Still please add the exact error message for future reference.  Good job on updating the question with the data requested.

Comment: @AllanWind it appears he was missing the `-I` for the Include Search Path. If you want to write up an answer explaining how to tell `gcc` where to find both the libraries and includes, I'll leave it to you. (and happily vote for a good answer)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Done.  I thought you would be a -Werror kind of guy :-)

Comment: @AllanWind -- I am, but if you are honest about resolving all warnings -- you can dispense with `-Werror`, on the other hand, if you need ti to ensure you don't bend the corners a bit -- it is a good way to keep you honest `;)`

Comment: highly recommend cmake to automatically generate makefiles which you build useing make instead of writing compiler commands by hand. https://cliutils.gitlab.io/modern-cmake/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compile a program that relies on a header file:

```
#include <gmp.h>
```

located in a non-standard location `/usr/local/include/gmp.h` you need to tell the compiler where to find it by setting the directory where to find the header file:

```
gcc -c main.c -I/usr/local/include
```

Note: `gpp -x c -v`

To link the program, you need to tell the compiler which library to use (`-l`) and where to find that library (`-L`) which in this case /usr/local/lib/gmp.a:

```
gcc main.o -o main -L/usr/local/lib -lgmp
```

Note: `gcc -print-search-dirs | grep ^libraries`

If you are using a dynamic library (.so), you may also need to tell the linker where to find the library at run-time:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
./main
```

Comment: Good job. You can also pass the runtime information to the linker to include `-rpath` to the library with `-Wl,-rpath=/path/to/your/lib` (avoids the export to the environment)

Comment: AFAIK, -rpath is considered evil (you are encoding something about the target environment that you may not control).

Comment: It all depends on what you are building for. If you are building for you personal project learning on your system with a library stuck in `/opt/local` -- well, it's less evil than if your were coding for your employer for a production system. Good to know both are available.